# How can I prevent user from scrolling ListView when they touch on screen

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application, I want to scroll `ListView` with Java code , I used this code to do that:

```
holder.items.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0, 0, 500000);
       }
    }
});
```

So my question is: How can I prevent user from scrolling `ListView` when they touch on screen but user able to touch `ListView` content?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by just assigning a listener to your ListView :

```
    listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true; // This Indicates that it has been handled by you
        }
        return false; 
    }
});
```

please retype the solution and don't copy paste (I've just wrote here (no intellicence))

Comment: No .. Thanks for your answer .. but I want in the moment of scrolling listview , I can select or touch or click items listview and don't stop scroll ...